# Fetch data in one table and use it to fetch more data in another table in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, vba

I have two tables in SQL SERVER which are 1)`tblBuyerCodes` 2)`tblStatistics`.

What I want to achieve in SQL Server is get a `buyer code` in the first table, fetch statistics in the second table of that buyer code and insert details in a 3rd table, let's call it `tblResults`. How can I achieve this in SQL Server stored procedure?

Specs:

```
tblBuyerCodes have columns (id, buyercode). 
tblStatistics have columns (id,buyercode,goodsbought,total). 
tblResults have columns (id, buyercode,goodsbought,total,date).
```

All I want to achieve is fetch results in tblStatistics and post them in tblResults basing on buyer codes fetched from the tblBUyerCodes table

```
For example results will be:
row 1: dm6 23 45689
row 2: dm8 45 3456
```

`dm6` and `dm8` being the buyer codes

Comment: Why not handle it all in SQL? Doing it in VBA, especially in a loop, is going to perform awfully compared to a set based approach.

Comment: As a stored procedure? Care to help how I can achieve that?

Comment: Not without some DDL and expected behaviour/results, no. At the moment, all I know is that you have 2 tables called `tblBuyerCodes` and `tblStatistics` and another that *might* be called `tblResults`.

Comment: tblBuyerCodes have columns (id, buyercode). tblStatistics have columns (id,buyercode,goodsbought,total). tblResults have columns (id, buyercode,goodsbought,total,date). All I want to achieve is fetch results in tblStatistics and post them in tblResults basinf on buyer codes in the tblBUyerCodes table. I hope this makes sense, I am a newbie to this

Comment: Not in the comments please

Comment: I updated my question @Larnu

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited detail we have, why not just?

```
INSERT INTO tblResult (id, buyercode,goodsbought,total,date)
SELECT id,
       buyercode,
       goodsbought,
       total,
       {SomeDateValue} --Maybe GETDATE()?
FROM tblStatistics;
```